# HELM admission is constantly creating Pod in status "Container Creating"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using K8S version 19.

I tried to install second nginx-ingress controller on my server (I have already one for Linux so I tried to install for Windows as well)

```
helm install nginx-ingress-win ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx 
-f internal-ingress.yaml 
--set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=windows 
--set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=windows 
--set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=windows 
--set tcp.9000="default/frontarena-ads-win-test:9000"
```

This failed with "Error: failed pre-install: timed out waiting for the condition".

So I have run helm uninstall to remove that chart

```
helm uninstall nginx-ingress-win
release "nginx-ingress-win" uninstalled
```

But I am getting Validation Webhook Pod created constantly

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                                                      READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE

nginx-ingress-win-ingress-nginx-admission-create-f2qcx    0/1     ContainerCreating   0          41m
```

I delete pod with `kubectl delete pod` but it get created again and again.

I tried also
`kubectl delete -A ValidatingWebhookConfiguration nginx-ingress-win-ingress-nginx-admission` but I am getting message `not found` for all combinations. How I can resolve this and how I can get rid off this?
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this `Pod` is managed by a `Deployment`,`StatefulSet`,`DaemonSet` etc., it will be automatically recreated every time you delete it, so trying to remove a `Pod` in most situations makes not much sense.

If you want to check what controlls this `Pod`, run:

```
kubectl describe pod nginx-ingress-win-ingress-nginx-admission-create-f2qcx | grep Controlled
```

You would probably see some `ReplicaSet`, which is also managed by a `Deployment` or another object. Suppose I want to check what I should delete to get rid of my `nginx-deployment-574b87c764-kjpf6` `Pod`. I can do this as follows:

```
$ kubectl describe pod nginx-deployment-574b87c764-kjpf6 | grep -i controlled
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nginx-deployment-574b87c764
```

then I need to run again `kubectl describe` on the name of the `ReplicaSet` we found:

```
$ kubectl describe rs nginx-deployment-574b87c764 | grep -i controlled
Controlled By:  Deployment/nginx-deployment
```

Finally we can see that it is managed by a `Deployment` named `nginx-deployment` and this is the resource we need to delete to get rid of our `nginx-deployment-574b87c764-kjpf6` `Pod`.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! You are real expert!
In my case it was some job that was controlling this creation so I did `kubectl delete job  nginx-ingress-win-ingress-nginx-admission-create` and it resolved the issue. But your explanation is great because you provided solution for general case that can serve for everyone!!! Amazing!

Comment: can you maybe assist me with my second trouble as well please? Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709259/kubernetes-cannot-have-windows-path-mounted-on-azure-file-share-linux-mountin