# Kubernetes HELM - how to create multiple NGINX Ingress controllers one for each Node

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have two nodes for my cluster: Windows and Linux. And I have one master node.
For Linux I installed NGINX controller and everything works perfectly fine!!!

```
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    -f internal-ingress.yaml \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```

So that NGINX Ingress Controller should target Linux Pod and that works!

Now I want to create NGINX Ingress Controller to target my second Node which is Windows.
Once I tried to create it it threw me `Error: timed out waiting for the condition`
I tried this command (very similar to working Linux command).

```
helm install nginx-ingress-win ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -f internal-ingress.yaml 
--set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=windows 
--set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=windows 
--set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=windows
```

Is it possible to have 2 NGINX Ingress Controllers? Why did it timeout? Am I doing something wrong?
What should be the correct command to install NGINX Ingress Controller for Windows?

Thank you

Comment: Is your nginx controller's image compatible with windows? I haven't heard of such a thing, but I (thankfully) don't have any experience trying to run kubernetes on windows. Either way, you'd want to increase the `helm` verbosity to get more information about where it's failing, and/or actually look at the cluster to see if (as I suspect) the Deployment is in a bad way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- helm install creates kubernetes objects in the current namespace of your context.
  You should use separate namespace for nginx-ingress-win release using --create-namespace --namespace namespacename flags
- Please run the helm install command with --debug flag to see what is the problem

Final Command :

```
helm install nginx-ingress-win ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -f internal-ingress.yaml 
--set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=windows 
--set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=windows 
--set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=windows 
 --create-namespace --namespace namespacename --debug
```

- Please provide the reason for having separate nginx controller for linux and windows nodes in the same cluster.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Where does nginx-ingress gets created - in Master Control Plane node or the first nginx has been created on my Linux nodes? Where does it reside? Thank you

Comment: And as someone mentioned it seems ngixn is not possible to be used for windows. can I use then the same which I created for linux to route traffic to Windows Pod Service for some dedicated Port? Because this nginx-ingress has reference to internal load balancer to create as well

Comment: As per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-internal-ip, The ingress controller needs to be scheduled on a Linux node. Windows Server nodes shouldn't run the ingress controller. A node selector is specified using the --set nodeSelector parameter to tell the Kubernetes scheduler to run the NGINX ingress controller on a Linux-based node. As per https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/, You can use services for cross-operating system connectivity. So your nginx ingress controller pod running on linux nodes should forward requests to windows pods via service.

Comment: Basically the nginx ingress controller pod is a L7 Reverse Proxy which just forwards requests to the service clusterIP configured in Kubernetes and if you can send requests to Windows Pods via service clusterIP, then the nginx ingress controller pod should also be able to do the same.

Comment: thank you, this clarifies! I was just affraid if it iso on Linux Node can it forward towards through the ClusterIp which is on Windows Node. Thanks.. Can you maybe help me with my second issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709259/kubernetes-cannot-have-windows-path-mounted-on-azure-file-share-linux-mountin

Comment: Replied for more information on the second issue