# Kubernetes mountPath with colon

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, mounted-volumes

I would like to add a column in my mountPath in Kubernetes like such:

```
 volumeMounts:
        - name: tdviniclaim 
          mountPath: /C:/Windows/
```

I know that it is not allowed, and is not working so I'm using a workaround to copy the files from C to C: within the pod like such:

```
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cp -r C C:"]
```

I know it's a bad way, so I wanted to ask if someone knows a better workaround for my problem. Unfortunately the mountPath has to be with the colon.

Best regards,

Jan

Comment: Have you tried putting the mountPath in quotes? `mountPath: "/C:/Windows/"`

Comment: Yes, but it throws an error while creating/applying the service, so that way doesnt work unfortunately.

Comment: try this mountPath: "C:\\Windows" also try filesharing the folder if just changing the mounthPath does not work

Comment: Unfortunatly that doesnt work, when I adjust the .yaml file and apply it, I receive a CreateContainerError with: "Warning  Failed     1s (x3 over 17s)  kubelet            Error: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: \Windows"

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column in mountPath in Kubernetes as mentioned below:

```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: "C:\\Windows"
  name: tdviniclaim
```

Refer to this [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66741164/19230181) and [Doc](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/providing-persistent-storage-to-windows-containers) for more information on Volume Mount for Windows.

Comment: Unfortunatly that doesnt work, when I adjust the .yaml file and apply it, I receive a CreateContainerError with: "Warning  Failed     1s (x3 over 17s)  kubelet            Error: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: \Windows"

Comment: @kaum : As per this [Github link] (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59876#issuecomment-390452420) Changing from path: C:/foo/bar to path: /C/foo/bar solved it. Can you try by giving this format.

Comment: Thanks Hemanth,
while this works, it doesnt create the folder structure Im looking for. 
It creates a new directory named C/... while I need a directory named C:/...

Comment: @kaum : Can you share the path which you are using ?

Comment: @kaum : Is your issue resolved? if not can you share the path how you are using?